# How do I read and transform CSV Headers before BigQueryIO.Write?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a csv file which contains headers as the first row. I'm reading it in and cleaning up those headers to match BigQuery column requirements. But I need a reference to the schema *before* the pipeline begins. What are the best practices for allowing BigQueryIO.Write to be responsive to the headers in this way? Currently my code looks something like this:

```
//create table
Table table = new Table();
// Where logically should the following line go?
TableSchema customSchema = ?
table.setSchema(customSchema);
TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
tableRef.setDatasetId("foo_dataset");
tableRef.setProjectId("bar_project");
tableRef.setTableId("baz_table");
table.setTableReference(tableRef);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadCSV").from("gs://bucket/file.csv"))
  // Detect if it's header row
  .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractHeader()))
  .apply(ParDo.of(new ToTableRow())
  .apply(BigQueryIO.Write.named("Write")
    .to(tableRef)
    // Where logically should the following line go?
    .withSchema(customSchema));
p.run();
```

I'm currently trying to implement perhaps two pipelines, looking (roughly) like the following, but the execution order is unreliable in Dataflow so I am getting errors where the BQ table doesn't exist.

```
PCollection readIn = p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadCSV").from("gs://bucket/file.csv"))
  .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractHeader()));
TableSchema customSchema = /* generate schema based on what I now know the headers are */
readIn.apply(ParDo.of(new ToTableRow())
  .apply(BigQueryIO.Write.named("Write")
    .to(tableRef)
    // Where logically should the following line go?
    .withSchema(customSchema));
p.run();
```

Comment: Hi @Mitch, can I ask what you do in ExtractHeader() ? I am trying to do the same thing, but cannot figure out how to retrieve the header info and use it in the next transformation (in your case, ToTableRow).

Comment: @NorioAkagi ExtractHeader is just looking through each row to match a certain condition, and then returning only that row. Unfortunately, this will not work. I had to abandon this approach for now, but you can use the new `DynamicDestinations` in Apache Beam 2.x to achieve a similar result. Hope this helps. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html

Comment: `DynamicDestinations` is useful when we want to dynamically change a BQ table depending on a row, but not header in my understanding. In my case, I need to import data from 3rd party PaaS and csv format is out of my control, and if all rows in one csv don't contain a certain field, it drops the field from an entire csv file, so I need to read the header and understand the data structure per each csv.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the reasons we had to move away from Beam for now.  The only other option for dealing with csv files is to preprocess in some way, for example convert the entire file to json in a container, and then process through Beam. But that obviously takes all of the streaming benefits away, and adds some significant overhead. We ended up hand-rolling a (not embarrassingly parallel at all) Java solution that works slowly and steadily.

Comment: I see. My current idea is, because we're going to use Airflow to post a job to DataFlow, I will read the first line from Airflow task in advance and send the header info as a parameter to Dataflow, then in Dataflow I can just skip the header and process remaining in a distributed manner. Anyway, thank you for the info! I really had difficulty just to see if there is any doo solution for a csv header analyzing as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature (dynamic schemas) is in review right now https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/2609 (I'm reviewing it). You can give a try to the in-progress PR, however note that its API is likely to change somewhat as a result of the review. I'll update this answer when the PR is submitted.

Comment: Thanks @jkff and thanks for getting to the gist of my question! I'm actually required by work to wait for 2.0.0 anyway, but will implement as soon as Beam is stable. In the meantime, would it be the "Dataflow way" to first read the file, strip the headers, and then pass that info to the pipeline?

Comment: Yes, I believe meanwhile you're stuck with having to first read the file and understand the schema, and then create a new pipeline passing the (already known) schema in there.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is now implemented via `DynamicDestinations` in 2.0.0? If so, hooray!

Comment: Yes, enjoy the new API :)